# Creating an html form and output things based off that data

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

I'm relatively new to HTML and I want to create a form so that the user can get a customized output based on their answers. I have a basic form with button inputs, with multiple tabs of buttons. Is there some way for me to collect the data that the user selects by pressing multiple buttons, and assign it to a js variable? This is the code I have so far.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
</head>
<style>
  /* Hide all steps by default: */
  
  .tab {
    display: none;
  }
  
  #myButton {
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-right: 2%;
    transition: margin-left 1s;
  }
  
  #myButton:hover {
    color: rgb(77, 77, 77);
    padding-left: 1%;
  }
  
  #main {
    padding-bottom: 25vh;
    padding-top: 25vh;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 5%;
  }
  
  /* Header */
  #heade {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #0F1116;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 3.25em 1.5em 1.5em 1.5em;
    z-index: 100;
  }
  
  header {
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    margin-top: -3px;
    padding-right: 80%;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <form id="regForm" style="text-align: center;" method="GET">
    <!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
    <div class="tab">
      <input onmousedown="myFunction()" name="qty" type="button" value="3" onclick="nextPrev(1)" id="myButton">
    </div>

    <div class="tab">
      <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
        <li><input name="qty" type="button" value="3" onclick="nextPrev(1)" id="myButton"></li>
        <li><input type="button" name=parameter value="Click me" onclick="nextPrev(1)" id="myButton"></li>
        <li><input type="button" value="Click me" onclick="nextPrev(1)" id="myButton"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="tab">
      <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
        <li><input name="qty" type="button" value="3" onclick="nextPrev(1)" id="myButton"></li>
        <li><input type="button" value="Click me" onclick="nextPrev(1)" id="myButton"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="tab">
      <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
        <li><input name="qty" type="button" value="3" onclick="nextPrev(1)" id="myButton" class="ug"></li>
        <li><input type="submit" value="Click me" onclick="nextPrev(1)" id="myButton" class="ug"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div style="overflow:auto;"></div>
    <div style="text-align:center;">
      <!-- Circles which indicates the steps of the form: -->
      <span class="step"></span>
      <span class="step"></span>
      <span class="step"></span>
      <span class="step"></span>
    </div>
    
    </div>

  </form>

</body>
<script>
  var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
  showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab

  function showTab(n) {
    // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
    x[n].style.display = "block";
    //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
    if (n == 0) {
      document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
    }
    if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
      document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
    }
    //... and run a function that will display the correct step indicator:
    fixStepIndicator(n)
  }

  function nextPrev(n) {
    // This function will figure out which tab to display
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
    // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
    if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
    // Hide the current tab:
    x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
    // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
    currentTab = currentTab + n;
    // if you have reached the end of the form...
    if (currentTab >= x.length) {
      // ... the form gets submitted:
      document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
      return false;
    }
    // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
    showTab(currentTab);
  }

  function validateForm() {
    // This function deals with validation of the form fields
    var x, y, i, valid = true;
    x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
    y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
    // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
    for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
      // If a field is empty...
      if (y[i].value == "") {
        // add an "invalid" class to the field:
        y[i].className += " invalid";
        // and set the current valid status to false
        valid = false;
      }
    }
    // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
    if (valid) {
      document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
    }
    return valid; // return the valid status
  }
</script>

</html>
```

There may be some extra code in there as this is part of a larger webpage.

Comment: can you explain a bit more on what you want to do? for an example do you want the users name to be displayed after he fills it in a textbox?

Comment: Essentially ill have a list of different characteristics, and the user can select each one, affecting the output. I can have certain lists such as color, type of clothing, brand, and when the user selects what they want it will assign it to a variable, that way you can find a matching product.

Comment: It's like a quiz that will collect the proper data and recommend products.